# single word for "inspiring/deserving of sympathy"

Tags: single-word-requests

eg.

> Because he hadn't done much of the homework, his confusion wasn't very deserving of sympathy.
>
> That character was always so cruel, his death didn't inspire any sympathy.

Anyone know one word that can be substituted in there? Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would probably go with what you've got.

Comment: I do prefer the second original one to all the answers because of the inclusion of the word "any" (and "inspire" reads well). It reinforces that there is not one iota of sympathy rather than very little. It is hard to get that across in the same sentence in the same way using the answers.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps

**Pitiable**
adjective
1. deserving or arousing pity.
(Google)

> "Because he hadn't done much of the homework, his confusion wasn't
>   very pitiable."
>
> "That character was always so cruel, his death wasn't pitiable."

Comment: Or its synonym `lamentable`. Upvote.

Comment: @TusharRaj lamentable's good. I'd upvote that.

Answer (score 2):

*[Heartbreaking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heartbreaking)*:

> adjective
>
> Causing overwhelming distress; very upsetting:
> <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*Because he hadn't done much of the homework, his confusion wasn't very **heartbreaking**.*

Comment: To be heartbroken and to feel sympathy for someone else are pretty different things, don't you think?

Comment: I agree. I think it's probably a little too strong. I can sympathize with someone without being distressed or upset at their predicament.

Comment: Agreed, but the context of negation welcomes a touch of embellishment :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pitiable or pathetic would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

emphasized text> **Hapless**
Use the adjective hapless to describe someone unlucky and deserving of pity.

> - deserving or inciting pity
> - “a **hapless victim**”

Usage examples-

The Astros were a team which for years had been a **hapless** loser
- ForbesJun 16, 2015

More than 900 died, most of them **hapless** young Argentine soldiers -
Washington Post, 2015
([Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/hapless))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/commiseration

Commiseration

Sympathy and sorrow for the misfortunes of others; compassion

Comment: You answer would be improved with an example of it's usage.

Comment: "Commiserable" to fit the examples?

Comment: @dwjohnston Should be its not it's. "There was no commiseration when he died."

Answer (score 0):

"That character was always so cruel, his death caused no **bereavement**."

> - bereavement - (noun) the condition of having been deprived of something or someone valued, esp through death. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bereavement)